# git in / not visible in /etc

Tags: git, git-branch

I am trying to put various configuration files and scripts in git but on this server git is behaving strangely and seems to refuse traversing parent directories to find the .git branch root.

```
/ # git init
/ # git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (use -u to show untracked files)
```

So far so good.

```
/ # cd etc/
/etc # git status 
# Not currently on any branch.
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

Huh? - Shouldn't I be on branch master?

If I try to add something:

```
/etc # git add passwd
fatal: Unable to create '//etc/.git/index.lock': No such file or 
directory
```

Why won't git search parent directories for the branch root (.git) ??

Comment: Try to delete the `index.lock` file.

Comment: Are you initializing git in your root directory? If so, any reason for that?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue (though I doubt what you're doing is a good idea). What's your environment (Distro/release, git version etc.)?

Comment: Can't remove index.lock - it doesn't exist:

    / # rm /.git/index.lock
    rm: cannot remove `/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory

Comment: It's an old Debian Squeeze server. Git is version 1.7.2.5

Answer (score 1):

You have previously initialized git in /etc. Delete /etc/.git and git will hit the /.git folder. Theoretically. I think for some obscure reason you cannot use /.git. You need to relocate it using the GIT_DIR environment variable.

Comment: There is no .git in /etc.

Comment: Actually this works: /etc # export GIT_DIR=/.git
/etc # git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (use -u to show untracked files)

Comment: Using /.git is a border case. Git stops searching for the .git folder when reaching the filesystem root folder. GIT_DIR is your best friend in that case.